# How to move echarts barchart to the left

Tags: bar-chart, echarts

I have an Echarts bar chart as show below. I want to fit the chart into the rectangle by moving it to the left. I can move the y-axis by using offset, but I want to move the entire chart to the left. Any suggestions?

```
option = {
  width: 350,
  height: 200,

  title: {
    show: true,
    text: 'Chart Title'
  },
  xAxis: {
    data: ['Oct 21', 'Nov 21', 'Dec 21', 'Jan 22', 'Feb 22', 'Mar 22']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    min: 70,
    max: 73,
    interval: 1,
    axisLabel: {
      formatter: '{value}'
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [71.98, 72.62, 72.26, 72.49, 71.91, 70.55],
      type: 'bar',
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#fce7a3'
      }
    }
  ],

  graphic: {
    type: 'rect',
    shape: {
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      width: 400,
      height: 300
    },
    style:{
      fill:'transparent',
      stroke:"#999"
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grid option. The left value can be either an integer or a percentage value or a string.

```
  grid:{
    left:40
  }
```

Refer [this](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid.left).